# How to sort csv file and select only required data using python?

Tags: python, database, sorting, csv

I have a really big csv file of 1.2GB.I want to sort that csv file using python and to show only required data.More Specifically actucally I have a csv file which includes all the schools of different states in my country(India),and I have only concern about schools in my state (Maharastra).So how can I sort this csv file and pick only maharastra state schools and shows its entire row?

P.S:- In 1st row is includes the header tuples(("STATNAME","DISTNAME","BLOCK_NAME","SCHCD","AC_YEAR","SCHNAME","RURURB","HABITATION_NAME","VILLAGE","PANCHAYAT","CUSTER_NAME","BLOCK_NAME_1","EDU_BLOCK","ASSEMBLY_CONSTITUENCY","MUNICIPALITY","CITY","CITYNAME","WEBSITE","SCH_CATEGORY","LOWCLASS","HIGHCLASS","SCHTYPE","SCHTYPES","SCHTYPEHS","SCHMGT","SCHMGTS","SCHMGTHS","DIST........))and many more information.
Now I want all information but only Maharastra's(STATE='MAHARASTRA')
How can I do it?
Can anyone pls help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiW1n.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged "database"?  Why do you need to sort the data to extract only certain records?

Comment: Tagged database , because I thought some Dev database analyst can also be aligible to give ans ! I wanted to sort and then extract that certain record so that the remaining data will be in convenient form ! @scott Hunter

Answer (score 0):

Look at "csv" from python at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.  this should get you close:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('schools.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
...     for row in reader:
...         if 'MAHARASTRA' in row:
...             print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy @Tom Scanlan.

Comment: @yogi, did that get you to a solution?

Comment: @ Tom Scanlan ,I have not executed yet,as that CSV file got corrupted (don't know why).Will let you know once I execute it.        Thnx!

Comment: hey @Tom Scanlan!sorry for the delay buddy, last night I run that programmer but its fetching error  as following:                                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 6700: invalid start byte
So what should I do next?